# Debugging a very large dataframe in pandas using Jupyter Notebool

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, debugging

I have a csv file with a column 'record' that has dictionaries (variable sized) as values and they are saved as 'str'. I read the file in a dataframe and am trying to get the dictionary keys separated out and added to the dataframe with the values of the keys as the values of the new columns. There are over 58k rows and when I run following lines on it, it keeps on failing with 'ValueError: malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.Name object at 0x17f1e73a0>'. Here is the code I am running:

```
   df["record"] = df["record"].astype('str').apply(lambda x: x.replace("null", "None"))

   df['record']=df['record'].astype('str').apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
   df.record.apply(pd.Series)
```

OK! so now the issue is how do I find which row in the 58K lines is giving this problem? When I run the same code on a very small dataframe, it worked fine. Please note: The question is not regarding exploding the column into multiple columns but rather help me debug and find which row is malformed.

Here is an example of the dataframe that works fine.

```
  df=pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 1689917349150,
  1: 1689917349356,
  2: 1689917349363,
  3: 1689917349552,
  4: 1689917349557,
  5: 1689917349764,
  6: 1689917349768},
 'record': {0: '{"tms_ProjectReleaseRelationship":{"project":{"uid":"myProj","source":"Jira"},"release":{"uid":"379000","source":"Jira"}}}',
  1: '{"tms_Release":{"uid":"426949","name":"2016.","description":null,"startedAt":null,"releasedAt":null,"source":"Jira"}}',
  2: '{"tms_ProjectReleaseRelationship":{"project":{"uid":"myProj","source":"Jira"},"release":{"uid":"123455","source":"Jira"}}}',
  3: '{"tms_Release":{"uid":"426951","name":"2016.13","description":null,"startedAt":null,"releasedAt":null,"source":"Jira"}}',
  4: '{"tms_ProjectReleaseRelationship":{"project":{"uid":"myProj","source":"Jira"},"release":{"uid":"426991","source":"Jira"}}}',
  5: '{"tms_Release":{"uid":"427240","name":"2016","description":null,"startedAt":null,"releasedAt":null,"source":"Jira"}}',
  6: '{"tms_ProjectReleaseRelationship":{"project":{"uid":"myProj","source":"Jira"},"release":{"uid":"427241","source":"Jira"}}}'},
 'index': {0: 56840,
  1: 56841,
  2: 56842,
  3: 56843,
  4: 56844,
  5: 56845,
  6: 56846})
```

Comment: Please copy paste the full trace of the error (no screenshot, format it). It seems your AST evaluation found a string that is not parsable as a dict which make it fails. A debugging option is to define a function performing the operation and catching the error then you will find the I'll defined lines and what it contains. Without the actual dataset it is impossible to tell. See [mcve] for details. Isolate the part of the CSV that is problematic and post it as well.

Comment: @jlandercy the question is not "why did the error happen?", but "how can I identify rows with strings that would trigger an error?"

Comment: As I said, write a function that perform the conversion and catch the error to print the problematic row and it's content when you perform apply.

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom function with [`try`/`except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
import ast
def check_malformed(s):
    try:
        ast.literal_eval(s)
    except:
        return True
    return False

invalid_rows = df.loc[df['record'].apply(check_malformed)]
```

Output:

```
              id                                             record  index
1  1689917349356  {"tms_Release":{"uid":"426949","name":"2016.",...  56841
3  1689917349552  {"tms_Release":{"uid":"426951","name":"2016.13...  56843
5  1689917349764  {"tms_Release":{"uid":"427240","name":"2016","...  56845
```

If you want to get the type of exception:

```
import ast
def check_malformed(s):
    try:
        ast.literal_eval(s)
    except Exception as e:
        return e.__class__.__name__

invalid_rows = df.assign(exception=df['record'].apply(check_malformed)).query('exception.notna()')
```

Output:

```
              id                                             record  index   exception
1  1689917349356  {"tms_Release":{"uid":"426949","name":"2016.",...  56841  ValueError
3  1689917349552  {"tms_Release":{"uid":"426951","name":"2016.13...  56843  ValueError
5  1689917349764  {"tms_Release":{"uid":"427240","name":"2016","...  56845  ValueError
```

To also have the error message:

```
import ast
def check_malformed(s):
    exception, error_msg = None, None
    try:
        ast.literal_eval(s)
    except Exception as e:
        exception, error_msg = e.__class__.__name__, e
    return pd.Series({'exception': exception, 'error_msg': error_msg})

invalid_rows = df.join(df['record'].apply(check_malformed)).query('exception.notna()')
```

Output:

```
              id                                             record  index   exception                                          error_msg
1  1689917349356  {"tms_Release":{"uid":"426949","name":"2016.",...  56841  ValueError  malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.Name ...
3  1689917349552  {"tms_Release":{"uid":"426951","name":"2016.13...  56843  ValueError  malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.Name ...
5  1689917349764  {"tms_Release":{"uid":"427240","name":"2016","...  56845  ValueError  malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.Name ...
```